# Migrating IBM AIX from "Power 8 to Power 9" processor

Tags: aix

Migrating IBM AIX from "Power 7 to Power 8" OR "Power 8 to Power 9" processor, Can any anyone help in sharing the process,script,guide, experience etc.

Comment: Not on here we can't. That's off-topic, too general, and asking for a recommendation.

Comment: Don't change the processor on your own, have trained engineers to do it. The change of processor in itself won't affect your programs (they might run faster, if you're lucky), but you might have to upgrade you AIX OS too (don't do that on your own either).

Comment: @Lorinczy: Actually situation demands this. AIX 7.2 is supported for both. I have checked few script that lets u make image of OS and boot another system with it. AIX has the mechanism of Live partition Mobility also. Next step, to replicate the older system is to configure the LPAR on new system or can go with Live partition Mobility.  I am looking for some professional approach or some one has experience in doing this.

Comment: There are AIX cloud providers which lets u move existing in house AIX system to their cloud. e.g Connectria, Site Ox, Triple C, Lpar, Skytap